# how to initialize a variable-sized object

Tags: c, variables, initialization

Is it possible to initialize a variable-sized object like `struct IP_addresses ip_addr[no_of_users] below`?

```
void foo(int no_of_users){
    struct IP_addresses{
       char IPaddr[16];
    };
    struct IP_addresses ip_addr[no_of_users];
    //.....
}

int main(void){
    int no_of_users = 4;
    foo(no_of_users);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I dont think your code will even compile

Comment: @user2408578: It compiles. C 1999 added variable-length arrays.

Comment: Have you tried compiling it, do you get any problems? I'm assuming you've first tried the code before posting a question here.

Comment: @angs: Do you mean can you initialize a variable-length array or can you define it?

Comment: Are you actually trying to initialize it? As in assign values to the elements of the array? Or just declare it. Your code as written compiles, but if you try to do array initialization like `struct IP_addresses ip_addr[no_of_users] = {"1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2"};`, then it will not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot initialize variable-length arrays. From C 2011 (N1570) 6.7.9, “Initialization”, paragraph 3:

> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete object type that is not a variable length array type.

You must assign values to the array by another method, such as a loop assigning each element.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tested it on gcc 3.4.4./cygwin and it works fine.

Comment: That's true, but I think the title of the question is just wrong. The OP may or may not be actually asking about initializing. It's yet to be determined.

Comment: @Devolus: That is a direct quote from draft N1570 of the ISO/IEC C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, interesting, that the standard says so, and yet the compilers seem to support it. Is there a section differeincing between local and global/static variables or is this all there is?

Comment: @Devolus: What code did you compile? The code in the question? That does not initialize a variable-length array. It just defines it.

Answer (score 2):

If what you mean is allocate/declare variable-sized objects, then ***yes*** in modern C compilers, it is possible for *local dynamic variables*. This is because all the compiler is going to do is bump the stack pointer to make room for your local vars when it enters the function, so by that time it knows the value of the parameter `no_of_users`.

It will generally *not* work for `static` variables because these do not live on the stack and are set up before the function is called.

It will also not work for any variables that the compiler needs to allocate if is not known at compile time how many to allocate. For instance:

```
static unsigned int no_of_users = 10;
static char var[no_of_users];

int main(void){
    return 0;
}
```

will not work, but this will:

```
#define no_of_users 10

static char var[no_of_users];

int main(void){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question does not ask whether you can define a variable-length array. It asks whether you can initialize it. You can define a variable-length array. You cannot initialize it.

Comment: Good point. I took from the OP's code example that what was really meant was declaring a variable-length array and the OP just didn't know there was a difference. We'll have to see which was really meant.

Answer (score 1):

Compiled with gcc 3.4.4 works fine.

However, it works, because this is a local variable on the stack. As sh1ftst0rm pointed out, it will not work with static/global variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void tester(int n)
{
    int sz[n];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sz[i] = 0;
}

int main()
{
    tester(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code compiles and works with gcc 4.4.5.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int no_of_users)
{
    struct IP_addresses
    {
        char IPaddr[16];
    };
    struct IP_addresses ip_addr[no_of_users];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < no_of_users; i ++)
        sprintf(ip_addr[i].IPaddr, "test%02d", i);

    for(i = 0; i < no_of_users; i ++)
        printf("%s\n", ip_addr[i].IPaddr);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, no_of_users;

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i ++)
    {
        no_of_users = strtol(argv[i], 0, 10);
        foo(no_of_users);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what those standards say, but in practice, it just works.  Here is what I got as the results:

```
$ gcc -o ./test ./test.c
$ ./test 3 4 5
test00
test01
test02
test00
test01
test02
test03
test00
test01
test02
test03
test04
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't initialize array in C during the runtime because the compiler has to reserved the space in advance (in the heap) for this syntax.

You have to use dynamic allocation (malloc and free).

Comment: Not true for local dynamic variables. These are allocated on the stack on most compilers are willing to wait until the function is called to determine how much space is needed in cases like this.